# Is it possible to store the facebook page post in cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I wanted to know is it possible to store the Facebook page post whenever a new post is created I wanted to store in a Firestore. like I will provide an endpoint and then whenever a new post is posted then it's response will be sent on that endpoint so i can easily store the posts in the Firestone. because i wanted to automate the comment reply to the users.

Answer (score 0):

*Webhooks* are what you are looking for.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

> Webhooks allows you to receive real-time HTTP notifications of changes to specific objects in the Facebook Social Graph. For example, we could send you a notification when any of your app Users change their email address or whenever they comment on your Facebook Page. This prevents you from having to query the Graph API for changes to objects that may or may not have happened, and helps you avoid reaching your rate limit.

Comment: so in my use case, i wanted to store the post information whenever it's created. is it possible? like i have created an endpoint /posts with method post so i can receive the post?

Comment: Your endpoint gets notified for all relevant changes for whatever field(s) you subscribe for. In this instance, you’ll want to subscribe to changes of the page `feed` field, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/#feed - but be aware that that sends updates for more than just posts, so you will have to filter out what is relevant to you on your end.

Comment: one last question in the documentation it said it will be notified to us when someone comments on the posts also?

Comment: or is it possible to get notified on webhook when someone comments on our post?and  like and share other than that there is no need of notification

Comment: Subscribing to `feed` should include all those already, yes.

Comment: is there any document available how we can setup my endpoint with Facebook. so i can test all the queries?

Comment: You see “Getting Started” in the menu on the left, yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218339/discussion-between-lucifer-luci-and-cbroe).